# Formula on contact to see if the first name is only 1 character long

Tags: formula, contact, if

We currently have a formula text field with the below formula:

`IF( FirstName =".",  text(Salutation) &" "& LastName ,  FirstName )`

but we want to add that if the first name is only 1 character long to the beginning if statement check.

any ideas?

Comment: There's no need to check if FirstName has a length of 1, because `FirstName = "."` can only be true if the length is one, and that one character is a `.`.

Comment: what we are trying to do is also check if the first name is just a single character like a or b not just "."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LEN function does this:

```
IF(LEN(FirstName)<2, Text(Salutation)&" "&LastName, FirstName)
```